# Can I stop Entity Framework AddOrUpdate from overwriting certain fields?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I generate some data in the seed method of an Entity Framework migration configuration file like so:

```
    public void DoSeed(eVendContext context) {
        //add a test station
        context.Stations.AddOrUpdate(
          p => p.Name,
          new eVendDbDataModel.Models.Station() {
              Name = "Test Station 1",
              Active = true,
              Created = DateTime.Now,
              Modified = DateTime.Now,
              Returnable = false,
              Type = "Test",
              PortNo = "COM1",
              Parse = false,
              UseJob = true,
              UseDept = true,
              JobAlias = "Job Number",
              DeptAlias = "Department",
              SiteId = 1
          });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

At application start up I call this method:

```
        //Always update database to latest version
        Database.SetInitializer<eVendContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<eVendContext, Configuration>());
```

Then for testing I'll go into the database directly and change `JobAlias` to `false`. The problem is the next time I run my app the seed method is called (even when there is no pending migrations) and updates my data, fixing `JobAlias` to `true` again.

Is there a way of easily stopping this behavior - so I can modify my DB data without it being overwritten next run?

Comment: The always-runs property is a dev feature, just write the appropriate code. AddorUpdate is most useful for fixed lookup data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if there is already any data in this table, to prevent its Seed, like this:

```
protected override void Seed(eVendContext context) 
{

    if (!context.Stations.Any())
    {   
          context.Stations.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name,
          new eVendDbDataModel.Models.Station() {
              Name = "Test Station 1",
              Active = true,
              Created = DateTime.Now,
              Modified = DateTime.Now,
              Returnable = false,
              Type = "Test",
              PortNo = "COM1",
              Parse = false,
              UseJob = true,
              UseDept = true,
              JobAlias = "Job Number",
              DeptAlias = "Department",
              SiteId = 1
          });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will have to do. Sorry for the delay - I was holding out for an easier/better solution - when you have 50+ settings checking each one can get annoying. I wrote a wrapper in the end.